# Inserting new records programatically in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to accomplish a purely administrative scripting task in mysql and I'd like to do it without writing a perl or php script or something.

Given the following `Table A`:

```
user_id | permission
--------------------
1         1
4         1
298       1
```

How would I give every `user_id` present in `Table A` the `permission` 5. (It needs to insert a new row for each `user_id` present in the table)

Comment: That would change all ther users permission from 1 to 5. I need to insert new rows.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question..  Please can you update your question with your table definition ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that will destroy his DB instead of adding new permissions.

Comment: The last line between parentheses is pretty clear?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: Hyperbolic much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert for each user in the table **another** row with permission 5 you can do

```
INSERT INTO TableA (user_id, permission)
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 5
FROM TableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tableA (user_id, permission) 
select distinct user_id, 5 from tableA
```

To give every unique user a new permission entry.